# How to check if an item has three specific class's and if so do this

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to do an if statement that detects if a list item has the class 'about' 'active' and 'item' assigned to it. every post i have read is to check if the item has one of the three classes. i want to know when the item has all three classes.
Please any help would be helpful thank you.

This is what i have so far

```
     var $activeItem =  $("#project05 ol.carousel-inner li.item");
    if ($activeItem.hasClass('about') & $activeItem.hasClass('active') & $activeItem.hasClass('item')) {
        alert("slide4 about is selected");
    }
```

HERE IS THE HTML

```
    <div id="project05" class="carousel slide">              
              <!-- Carousel items -->
              <ol class="carousel-inner">
                <li class="item home active">
                </li>
                <li class="item about">
                </li>
                <li class="item solutions">
                </li>
                <li class="item approach">
                </li>
              </ol>
              <!-- Carousel nav -->
              <ol class="carousel-linked-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#1">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#3">Solutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#4">Approach</a></li>
              </ol>
              <a class="carousel-control left" href="#project05" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
              <a class="carousel-control right" href="#project05" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>
```

Here is the answer for what i was looking for, for those who might want to know.

```
    function carouselSlide() {
    $('#exterior-page .carousel').bind('slid', function() {
      $('#exterior-page.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');
      var idx = $('#exterior-page .carousel .item.active').index();
      $('#exterior-page .carousel-linked-nav li:eq(' + idx + ')').addClass('active');
      if(idx === 0) {
          // alert("home page");
          $("#main-nav").removeClass();
          $("#main-nav").addClass('home-color');
        }
        else if(idx === 1) {
           // alert("about page");
           $("#main-nav").removeClass();
           $("#main-nav").addClass('about-color');
        }
        else if(idx === 2) {
           // alert("solutions page");
           $("#main-nav").removeClass();
           $("#main-nav").addClass('solutions-color');
        }
        else if(idx === 3) {
           // alert("approach page");
           $("#main-nav").removeClass();
           $("#main-nav").addClass('approach-color');
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need to check `item? It was in the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Musa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17659197/1456376) has already my upvote, but here's a little addition as it <del>is</del> was missing this case:

Your selector can return multiple items if the class `item` is present on more than one `<li>`-element. In this case:

```
if ($activeItem.is('.about.active')) {}
```

will always return `true` if at least one element has the specific classes. If multiple entries can have the class `item` you can check the result in a loop like this:

```
$.each($activeItem, function(key, value) {
    if ($(value).is('.active')) {
        alert ('Slide ' + key + ' is selected');
    }
});
```

**OR**

Another idea is to select the element directly and to get the index like this:

```
var selected = $('ul li.active').index();
```

You can add `+ 1` to the `key` or to the statement right above if you want as both values are zero-based.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/MLcVv/)

**Edit**

It seems, that you're using [Twitter BootStrap Carousel](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel). If it is the case, you can bind the `slid`-event, which fires after each action (like clicking the prev/next buttons or using the navigtion). This should do the trick:

```
$('.carousel').bind('slid', function() {
    var selected = $('ul li.active').index();
});​
```

Comment: So i still have not found an answer that is working. i think i need to do some kind of loop that cycles through the list items and then searches for the list item that has the following three class's applied to it. But again i am not quite sure how to do it since every attempt i have made has failed.

Comment: I see you've updated the question. To get the number of the selected `li` use my second approach like this: `var selected = $('ol.carousel-inner li.active').index();`. If for example this value is `1` than `about` is selected.

Comment: So i like the way you use your logic using the index(), but it only only runs the the list once the dom is loaded and then it quits so it will never alert anything if i had the index set to 1 only is it was set to 0 since the home page is the first list loaded. Need a way so that it constantly is looping through the ordered list items. Thank you for the help you have given so far:)

Comment: It's just really frustrating that something as simple as this is causing me so many problems. need a way to have the function constantly loading in the background i believe.

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller Don't worry. I've added a new part to the answer. Hopefully, it's the right direction.

Comment: Sorry little confused on how i wont implement this in my code. would you mind being more specific please? thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
if ($activeItem.is('.about.active')) {
    alert("slide4 about is selected");
}
```

I didn't include `item` because it is used in the selector to select `$activeItem` so if an item is selected it will already have that class. If sometime later you want to test for the 3 classes when perhaps the classes of the elements could change use `if ($activeItem.is('.about.active.item')){`

Note `is` will return true if any `li` has the classes, if you want to test on an individual basis then

```
$activeItem.each(function(){
    if ($(this).is('.about.active')) {
        alert("slide4 about is selected");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
& $activeItem.hasClass('active')
```

supposed to be

```
&& $activeItem.hasClass('active')
```

Condition has to use **double &**

Your if should look like this

```
 if ($activeItem.hasClass('about') && $activeItem.hasClass('active') 
                                   && $activeItem.hasClass('item')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var $activeItem =  $("#project05 ol.carousel-inner li.item");
if ($activeItem.hasClass('about') && $activeItem.hasClass('active') && $activeItem.hasClass('item')) {
    alert("slide4 about is selected");
}
```

You need two `&` for "and" in the condition.

This might be better:

```
if ($activeItem.is('.about.active.item')) {
    alert("slide4 about is selected");
}
```

Or, depending, you might be able to do this:

```
var $activeItem =  $("#project05 ol.carousel-inner li.item.active.about");
```

Which would only return the item if it has the right classes to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

> $activeItem.is('.about , .active, .item')